# How can i customize Language Selection Dialog in installshield Basic MSI project?

Tags: installation, installshield, installation-package

I want to modify default UI design of language selection dialog in basic msi project of installshield....

Comment: In InstallShield 2012 the Suite project type allows you to edit all the dialogs; it can then deploy the Basic MSI project. Basic MSI projects themselves still have a few dialogs such as this which are shown by the bootstrap and have no supported way to edit them.

Comment: But what is the difference between suit project type and basic MSI project type...??
and can i convert Suit project into Basic MSI project..??

Comment: The Suite project collects and deploys other projects. So if you wanted to use it, you'd build your multilingual MSI and then wrap it up in a suite and build that.

Comment: Can you provide me a demo application or tutorial for suite project...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language selection dialog is shown by an EXE bootstrapper. Since it's an internal resource in a custom EXE, the only way to modify it is to somehow edit the resource files inside that EXE.

Comment: Thanks Cosmin Pirvu,

but can you suggest me how to modify resource files of the EXE..??

Comment: You can try any EXE resource editor: http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=exe+resource+editor